# Access 2007 vba null

Tags: ms-access, vba, null

My program doesn't process past this statement:

```
Dim valid as Boolean
If MyComboBox.Value Is Not Null Then valid = true
```

Why not?

If I try to step through using stop points the program does not proceed to the next step, but the form keeps running as if no vba code is being run. This is annoying because it means the form can still be used as if nothing is wrong but the intended behavior is not occuring.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What do you expect it to do? `Valid` is a `Boolean` variable that you only set if a bad test meets one condition, and you do nothing with `Valid` afterward in the code you posted. (A better test would be more like `If MyComboBox.Text <> ""`, or `Valid = MyComboBox.Text <> ""`, and then do something depending on whether `Valid` is true or false.)

Comment: Testing for `MyComboBox.Text` in Access is going to work only when the control has the focus. Checking if the control is Null is the best solution (`If IsNull(Me!MyComboBox))`), assuming that the data field it's bound to disallows zero-length strings (as they should, but which is no longer the default in the Access table designer, unfortunately).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IS keyword is used for testing the state of objects and you want to test a value.  The following works fine:

```
Dim Valid as Boolean

If Not IsNull(MyComboBox.Value) Then Valid = True
```

See the following link for a more detailed description:

[Nothing? Empty? Missing? Null?](http://allenbrowne.com/vba-NothingEmpty.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was very informative. Your answer provided the solution I needed.

Comment: Or, more simply, `Valid = (Not IsNull(Me!MyComboBox))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function this way (at least in Excel) raises an error, because `Null` AFAIK can only be used to test objects (and the value property is not an object).

Therefore... if you want to set valid = `TRUE` when there is at least one selected value in the Combobox, I believe I'd use

`valid = CBool(Len(MyCombobox.Value))`

Hope it helps... and hope I haven't misunderstand your question :-)

Comment: Null is a possible value of a variant, not of an object.